# Updating a database with a small csv file

Tags: c#, sql, database, csv, import

For an application I need to compare a csv file with a table from my database. If the record does not exist in the database I need to create it. If the records are different I need to update the database. And finaly if a record does not exist in the csv I need to delete it from the database. All this needs to be done with a C# program.

What is the best aproach for this problem? Any help is welcome.

Edit-
Until what file size is dropping table and importing the csv file the best way to go ?

Comment: So why don't you just clear the table and then insert all records from the CSV file ?

Comment: Well the point is I am completely unfamiliar with imports like this. That is why I was wondering what the best aproach is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you will be making all data in the DB the same with CSV file, I believe the file size does not matter here. If you compare each row in the CSV file with the data in DB, then you will need at least to do a SELECT on the data, store it all in memory, then do a compare and perform the operation you want. But this is less practical than just clearing the table and insert all records from the CSV file.